# How to execute cmd command in the container up with TestContainers?

Tags: java, bash, cmd, samba, testcontainers

I can execute command (inside the container started with testcontainers) from cmd. I want to execute the same comamnd from testcontainers api

```
/ # LDB_MODULES_PATH=/usr/lib/samba/ldb/ ldbmodify -H /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb /tmp/test.ldif 
Modified 0 records successfully
```

[image]

**option1:**

```
sambaContainer.execInContainer(
            "LDB_MODULES_PATH=/usr/lib/samba/ldb/",
            "ldbmodify",
            "-H",
           "/var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb",
            "/tmp/test.ldif",
        )
```

I get the error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "LDB_MODULES_PATH=/usr/lib/samba/ldb/": stat LDB_MODULES_PATH=/usr/lib/samba/ldb/: no such file or directory: unknown
```

I tried 2 options:

**option 2:**

```
sambaContainer
            .withEnv("LDB_MODULES_PATH","/usr/lib/samba/ldb/" )
            .execInContainer(
            "ldbmodify",
            "-H",
           "/var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb",
            "/tmp/test.ldif",
        )
```

I get the error:

```
WARNING: Module [samba_dsdb] not found - do you need to set LDB_MODULES_PATH?
Unable to load modules for /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb: (null)
Failed to connect to /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb - (null)
```

Result of the second option is the same as executing

```
ldbmodify -H /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb /tmp/test.ldif
```

from cmd:

[image]

How to execute the command from testContainers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
val sambaContainer = GenericContainer(SAMBA_IMAGE)
                     ...
                    .withEnv("LDB_MODULES_PATH","/usr/lib/samba/ldb/")
sambaContainer.start()
sambaContainer.execInContainer(
                "ldbmodify",
                "-H",
               "/var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb",
                "/tmp/test.ldif",
            )
```